# why php echoed image shows only thumbnail of the image?

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

**MY PHP CODE IS BELOW**
echoed image shows only its thumbnail

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        $userid =  $_SESSION['user_id'] ;
        $query = "SELECT img FROM user where iduser='{$userid}' LIMIT 1 ";
        $result_set = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)){
            echo $row['img'];
            if(is_null($row['img'])){
            echo '<img  src="assets/images/fuser.png" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height:256px;width:256px">';
            }else{
            echo '<img src="assets/images/"'.$row['img'].'" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height:256px;width:256px">';
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

My image shows like this
https://i.stack.imgur.com/noY9x.jpg

Comment: You're using Bootstrap's `img-thumbnail` class!

Comment: yes..but that's not the reason.. I removed that class and tried again..but still got the same problem.Just check below link  https://imgur.com/a/uXcdytz

Comment: That means that there is something wrong with the source (`src`) of the image, it seems the problem is in your echo string, see my answer for explanation.

Answer (score 1):

The html you're echoing is ill-formed:

```
echo '<img src="assets/images/"'.$row['img'].'" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height:256px;width:256px">';
```

For `$row['img']` that's `image1.jpg`, your code will echo this:

```
<img src="assets/images/"image1.jpg" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height:256px;width:256px">
```

Which has an additional unnecessary quote in the `src` attribute, so the image `src` destination won't exist, your echo should be (after removing the `"` after `images/`):

```
echo '<img src="assets/images/'.$row['img'].'" class="img-responsive img-thumbnail" style="height:256px;width:256px">';
```

Also make sure that your php file is in the folder `assets/`.